# Vieta's formulas for $x^2+px+1$ and $x^2+qx+1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots for $x^2+px+1$ and let $\gamma$ and $\delta$ be the roots
>   for $x^2+qx+1$. Show that $$(\alpha-\gamma)(\beta-\gamma)(\alpha+\delta)(\beta+\delta)=q^2-p^2.$$

This seemed to be rather peculiar. It should be a simple application of Vieta's formulas, but I couldn't get it to the form they wanted...

We have $\alpha+\beta=-p$, $\alpha\beta=1$ and $\gamma+\delta=-q$, $\gamma\delta=1$.

Also $\alpha^2+p\alpha+1=0 \Rightarrow p = -\alpha-\frac{1}{\alpha} \Rightarrow p^2 = \alpha^2+2+ \frac{1}{\alpha^2}$

and $\gamma^2+q\gamma+1=0 \Rightarrow p = -\gamma-\frac{1}{\gamma} \Rightarrow q^2 = \gamma^2+2+ \frac{1}{\gamma^2}$.

This should imply that $q^2-p^2 = (\gamma^2+2+\frac{1}{\gamma^2})-(\alpha^2+2+ \frac{1}{\alpha^2}) = \gamma^2+\frac{1}{\gamma^2} - \alpha^2-\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$.

What should I do here?

Comment: Hint: $x^2 + px + 1 = (\alpha - x)(\beta - x)$. Therefore, $(\alpha - \gamma)(\beta - \gamma) = \gamma^2 + p \gamma + 1$. You can similarly find the other term with $\delta$ and then evaluate the product and simplify the expression using Vieta's formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Note $x^2+px+1= (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$. Then

\begin{align}
& (\alpha-\gamma)(\beta-\gamma)(\alpha+\delta)(\beta+\delta)\\
= &(\gamma^2+p\gamma +1)(\delta^2-p\delta +1)\\
= &(\gamma\delta)^2+\delta^2 +\gamma^2+1-(\gamma\delta)p^2\\
 = &(\delta+\gamma)^2-2\gamma\delta+2-p^2\\
=&q^2-p^2
\end{align}

where $\gamma+\delta=-q $ and $\gamma\delta=1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you get the $(\gamma\delta)p^2$ term on the second equality? I seem to get the result $(\gamma^2+p\gamma +1)(\delta^2-p\delta +1) = (\gamma\delta)^2 + \delta^2 + \gamma^2 + 1 - \gamma^2 p \delta + \delta^2 p \gamma - p^2 \gamma \delta + p\gamma - p\delta$?

Comment: @Nate - note $-\gamma^2 p\delta = -p\gamma (\gamma\delta) = -p\gamma$, which cancels $p\gamma$. Similarly, $ \delta^2p\gamma$ cancels $-p\delta$

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this e.g.

Sorry for the image but it would take me 1 hour to type this in MathJax.

[image: solution5050]

Answer (score 0):

Regrouping the factors, one has $$(\beta-\gamma)(\alpha+\delta)\cdot(\alpha-\gamma)(\beta+\delta)$$
$$=(\beta\delta-\gamma\alpha)(\alpha\delta-\gamma\beta)$$
$$=\delta^2-\beta^2-\alpha^2+\gamma^2$$
$$=(\delta+\gamma)^2-2\delta\gamma-(\beta+\alpha)^2+2\beta\alpha$$
$$=(\delta+\gamma)^2-(\beta+\alpha)^2$$
$$=q^2-p^2,$$ where one uses $\alpha\beta=\gamma\delta=1$ during the process.

**Note**. Your last step equals $$\gamma^2+\delta^2-\alpha^2-\beta^2$$ which can be simplified as above.

Answer (score 0):

As $\alpha\beta=\gamma\delta$

assuming  $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$ are non-zero & finite,

let $\dfrac\alpha\gamma=\dfrac\delta\beta=k$(say)

$$-p=\alpha+\beta\implies \beta+k\gamma+p=0\  \ \ \  (1)$$

$$\text{Similarly, }\beta k+\gamma+q=0\  \ \ \  (2)$$

Find $(1)+(2), (1)-(2)$

Hope you can take it from here?